# Generating completely dynamic SQL with linq

Tags: .net, sql, linq, dynamic-sql

I've been using Linq to Entity Framework for a while and have been loving it.

However, I am now in a situation where I need to query a completely dynamic database table on sql server. I do not know the table name, structure or column names at compile time.

Is there a way of using Linq like syntax to compile a SQL query? I am given the table name and column names at runtime, and I will need to do complex searches (e.g. where cola = x and (cola = y or colb = z) or (colc in n..p)), with order by's and potentially group bys

I have found something which looks promising, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx, but I don't understand a) how to dynamically choose an arbitrary table b) how to prevent injection. The author says there is more in "part 2" - but I can't find any links to it and the blog is from 2008.

I am imagining some syntax like

```
public void SelectPizzasCheaperThan(int price) {
    var table = con.selectDB(tablename);
    var result = table.where(x => x.Field<string>("Food") = "Pizza");
    result = result.where(x => x.Field<int>("price") < price);
    result = result.select(x => new {Name = field<string>("Name"), Price = field<int>("price")}).ToList();
}
```

(obviously, those hard coded strings will be arbitrary variables defined at run time)

Is there anything like this already? In particular, anything from Microsoft?

Thanks for reading

Comment: If the database is complete dynamic and not know at compile time then why EF?

Comment: Sorry no, I am not intending to use EF. However, I do like the EF syntax with injection safety and lazy evaluation. I was wondering if there is anything similar to EF, but without the compile time entities

Comment: It's not "EF syntax" that you are after. It's called LINQ. There's LINQ to XML, LINQ to Objects, and even LINQ to SQL etc. Each of these may have their own specific methods to handle the type of data they're working with but the syntax is similar.

Comment: @Nick Yes there is SQL to LINQ but without a know database to create and object model from it loses a lot.

Comment: You didn't read my comment. I was pointing out that LINQ was not specific to Entity Framework.

Comment: @nick Yes but SQL to LINQ is specifice to SQL and if there are no tables and columns at design time it cannot build an object model.

Comment: Hi Nick - could you elaborate on Linq to Sql? I can only find results on google which look like EF (i.e. static compile time classes). Is EF === Linq2Sql or are they different?

Comment: @Blam with the impressive description in your profile you shouldn't be having such a hard time comprehending what I'm saying. And for the record it's officially "LINQ to SQL". My first comment clearly states LINQ itself does not belong to any particular technology , but the implementations for each of those technologies will have methods specific to them.

Comment: @Nick OK LINQ to SQL.  What part of .Where(x => x.Property = ...) is NOT available if Property is not know at design time is not clear?  If the tables and columns are not know then there are no strongly typed properties.  Can we agree that x.Field<string>("Food") = "Pizza" is not the same as x.Food = "Pizza" and x.Food will not throw a run time exception but x.Field<string>("Food") might?

Comment: @Blam You are right and I never said you weren't. I was only stating that the syntax he's been using to query his entities with EF isn't exactly specific to EF. Some methods in LINQ will only work depending on what you're using. If I originally wrote that poorly I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are injection safe.

[SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Use switch (if elseif) for SqlDbType but you can build them up dynamically.

Comment: The bit I have issues with is the "Dim commandText As String = _
     "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics " _
     & "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;" "
Is there a way to make a dynamic sql statement? E.g. use a parse tree generated through lazy evaluated linq, and compile a SQL string?

Comment: Not that I know of.  LINQ EF is compile time.  You stated tables and columns are not know at compile time.  The database engine is what compiles a SQL statement.  String (commmand text) is a variable and can be assigned at assigned at run time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by database engine?
I had presumed that linq to ef simply uses reflection from data provided at compile time, is it possible to use this "database engine" at run time to ensure SQL statement and parse tree correctness?

Comment: But you said you did NOT have tables or columns at compile time.  You are NOT going to be to build strongly typed LINQ at compile time.  The .NET compiler has no knowledge of SQL syntax.  If the syntax fails then SQL will throw an error.   Even with your dynamic LINQ if tablename or "Food" is wrong LINQ is not going to catch it - SQL will throw an error.

Comment: I am fine with SQL throwing an error if the column does not exist, I understand the compiler cannot catch that.

Comment: However, somewhere in the Entity Framework (or Linq to sql?), it knows the SQL syntax. I was wondering if you could give it the name of the column from a variable, and it would insert that into the SQL it generates at run time

Comment: OK then use the dynamic LINQ.  It will put a column where a column should be and table where a table should be.  And it will build up a where.  TSQL is kind of automatic for me but I see where you are coming from.